# DOM walk javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-framework

how to get the value out of the picturesPortals from here

```
 -Screen
    - Customers
      + 0
      + 1
      - 2
         +testings
         - Portals
             -pictureportal
              + 0
              - 1
                 - name             "portal 1"
```

Above is how it renders in firefox DOM. I want to alert out the value of name in pictureportal
 I tried

```
 alert(Screen.Customers[2]['Portals']['pictureportals'][1]['name']);
```

But that didnt work

Comment: `pictureportal` is singular not plural

Comment: Show us the HTML. The indentation means nothing when you talk about the DOM.

Comment: You cannot access the DOM like that. I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_Javascript and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you're trying to walk the DOM, but access a deep object property.

If that's right, it would be something like this:

```
Screen.Customers[2].Portals.pictureportal[1].name
```

*Note that I'm using using `pictureportal` and not `pictureportals`.*